# Backtesting Precision / use_bar_magnifier

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I see that Backtesting Precision / use_bar_magnifier  was added.  I believe this will help with the false results that we get in running backtests.

It seems to be only using a bar magnifier/ precision until about 6months /1 yearish on a daily chart test.   Results do not change on multiple pairs after the most recent year when looking at the daily or 12 hour for chart time.

I have a hard time believing that only miscalculated trades occured in the past year and the last 2,3,4,5,6 etc years nothing.

What is the time limit for the use bar magnifier to look back?  My gut feeling is its the max time you can look back for a chart time frame.  which would be around Jan 2019 for the daily as the is the limit to the 1 hour.  But then there should be different results going back to 2019 vs 2022/ middle of 2021 when testing the daily.

Answer (score 1):

There is limitations of the [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf) function (which is used by the bar magnifier feature) it can access a maximum of 100,000 intrabars.
So it is true, with the `bar magnifier` option the strategy will process only `x` last available bars when sum of requested dataset from  the lower time-frame is less than 100000.